# Invalid Hook Call with react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, next.js, react-hook-form

I am new to react hook form so this may be a simple issue. I just discovered that Controllers do not have the ability to use value as number. This was aggravating , but I eventually found this github issue [#8068](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/8068) which describes the solution as setting an onChange function like this:

```
<Controller
-    rules={{ valueAsNumber: true }}
      render={({ field }) => (
          <input
-             onChange={field.onChange}
+             onChange={(event) => field.onChange(+event.target.value)}
              type="number"
          />
  )}
/>
```

So I did some slight altering and came up with this code

```
import React, { ChangeEvent } from 'react'
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
import { getPlaceholder } from './getPlaceholder'
import { IInput } from './types'

const NumberInput: React.FC<IInput> = ({ control, name, ...props }) => {
  const placeholder = getPlaceholder({ type: "number" });
  const numericalOnChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.value === '') return null;
    return +event.target.value;
  }

  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({ field: { onChange, ...field } }) => (
        <input
          {...props}
          {...field}
          type="number"
          placeholder={placeholder}
          onChange={(event) => {
            const value = numericalOnChange(event)
            onChange(value)
          }}
          className="h-[20px] pl-[4px] py-[8px] bg-transparent border-b
          border-b-[#646464] focus:border-b-[#3898EC] text-[13px]
          text-[#F00] placeholder-[#646464] outline-none m-1 w-full"
        />
      )}
    />
  )
}

export default NumberInput
```

which in theory should work, but ends up providing an Invalid Hook Call Error.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `NumberInput` component separately and then wrap it in `Controller` directly inside the form:

```
// NumberInput.js
export const NumberInput = ({ value, onChange, ...rest }) => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    onChange(Number(e.target.value));
  };
 
  return (
    <input
      type="number"
      min={0}
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={value}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};
```

Then inside the component where you call `useForm`:

```
<Controller
  name='number'
  control={control}
  render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
    <NumberInput {...field} type="number" />
  )}
/>
```

You can find more info in [this post](https://claritydev.net/blog/managing-forms-with-react-hook-form#handling-number-inputs).